# Using global SCSS variables in an AstroJS project

Tags: css, sass, global-variables, astrojs

I'm new to AstroJS. I have a `styles` folder in the `src` folder with a file called `global.scss` where I define global SCSS variables like this:

```
/* SCSS HEX */
$aquamarine: #44ffd1ff;
$pomp-and-power: #8d6a9fff;
$space-cadet: #1a1b41ff;
$argentinian-blue: #5da9e9ff;
$burnt-sienna: #ee6c4dff;
```

I have an `index` page within my `layouts` folder. How do I access these global SCSS variables in my pages or layout components? I've tried importing it at the top like this:

```
import '../styles/global.scss';
```

When I attempt to use the SCSS color variables defined in `global.scss` it doesn't work. I was under the impression I could use the variables in my style tag like this `background-color: $aquamarine;`

Answer (score 0):

I am also using AstroJS with SCSS. Perhaps what I have done will work for you. In the `global.scss` file, declare variables using a custom property name that begins with a double hyphen (--), like normal CSS variables, not SCSS variables. Also, define custom properties on the `:root` pseudo-class so they can be applied globally:

```
/* global.scss */

    :root {
        --gold: #b59241;
        --gold-light: #d9c596;
        --gray-light: #f4f4f4;
    }
```

Then import your `global.scss` file exactly as you have been doing, into your Astro component, layout or page, between the --- code fences. Next, add style tags and access the global variable(s) using `var()`.

```
---
/* Header.astro */
                    
import '../styles/global.scss';
---
            
<style>
.navbar {
 height: 37px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background: var(--gray-light);
}
<style>
                
                
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar" aria-label="Primary">
...
</nav>
```

Lastly, be sure to install the `.scss` and `.sass` preprocessor package into your Astro project:

```
npm add -D sass
```